# Matplotlib showing empty plot in for loop

Tags: python, function, for-loop, matplotlib, seaborn

I defined a custom function and saved a list of values into shoreline variable. I am certain there is variable in this variable because I tried print(shoreline) and I was able to get a list of values.

This for loop will loop through 'folders' and give shoreline a different list every time.

Now if I try the code below, the output plot is empty. The weird thing is I was able to get correct title, and the title was derived from value. But the value argument was somehow not passed into plot.

It's not problem of plt.show() because the plot is shown in the output window but it doesn't contain any data.

[image: empty plot]

The correct plot I was expecting is something like this (using different data) [image: correctplot]
Can some one help me solve this?

```
from production import get_volume
for args in folders:
    shoreline = get_volume(args)
    
    import seaborn as sns
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import statistics 
    median = statistics.median(shoreline)
    sns.set_style("ticks")
    ax1=sns.distplot(shoreline, bins=70, color="#1B87C0",
                     kde_kws={"color": "k", "lw": 0.7, "alpha":0.8, "label": "KDE"},) 
    ax1.set(xlabel = 'Elevation (m)', ylabel='Kernel density')
    ax1.set_title('Shoreline elevation distribution\n'+ args.stem+'\nMedian = '+str(median))
    plt.legend(frameon=False, loc='upper left')
    figname = str(figure_path/ 'Shoreline_{}.png'.format(args.stem))
    plt.savefig(figname, dpi = 300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

**EDIT: Matplotlib's autoscale did not work somehow, my data has a range from 81-100 and the axis goes all the way to 1e6, that's why the plot seems to be empty. **

Comment: A side note: do not import modules in a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! i tried putting the modules outside, it was still showing me a empty plot.

Comment: What is `shoreline`? What is its data type and dimensions, if any?

Comment: the shoreline is a list of floats like [89.7, 89.9, 90.0], it has around 200 values. Shoreline is just the name i gave to the list.

Comment: could you try setting ax1.set_ylim(0,5) or something within reasonable range ?

Comment: Yes, I tried setting the ylimit. Usually matplotlib or seaborn will auto adjust the axis for the data. I still can't see anything after adjusting ylim

Comment: Yes I know it usually adjusts, but the current limits seem really unusual (including xlim, if the data in shoreline is similar to that in your example chart)

Comment: I'm not sure the is anything wrong with the code, but as @dm2 said, you may want to adjust the y axis in case you have an extreme outlier. The code works with a random normal distribution.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, SETTING THE LIMIT WORKED!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is answered in the one of the comments, Matplotlib's autoscale did not work somehow, my data has a range from 81-100 and the axis goes all the way to 1e6, that's why the plot seems to be empty. After adjust adjust xlim, the plot started to show up correctly.

Answer (score -1):

hi i am new to matplotlib but i do not see the line

plt.show()

have you tried that?

Comment: hi, I am using jupyter notebook, I tried plt.show(), plt.show() will show the figure, but the problem here is the data is not being passed in somehow.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Could you share your final code as it would be great to learn from this in the future.